# DialogFragment containing a DatePicker Crashing with InflateException on devices running Android M

Tags: android, datepicker, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a DialogFragment containing a DatePicker which is working fine for devices running 5.0 and below but crashing on Android M.

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, DatePickerDialog.OnCancelListener {

    Calendar calendar;
    onDateTimeSetCallBack callBack;

    public DatePickerFragment() {
    }

    public void setData(Calendar calendar, onDateTimeSetCallBack callBack) {
        this.callBack = callBack;
        this.calendar = calendar;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day); //<---- CRASH HERE
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        callBack.onDateSet(year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        callBack.onDateCancel();
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime: Process: , PID: 25371
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.DatePicker
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/  E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at .fragment.NewFavoriteFragment$DatePickerFragment.onCreateDialog(NewFavoriteFragment.java:437)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:407)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.DatePicker
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at .fragment.NewFavoriteFragment$DatePickerFragment.onCreateDialog(NewFavoriteFragment.java:437) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:407) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at .fragment.NewFavoriteFragment$DatePickerFragment.onCreateDialog(NewFavoriteFragment.java:437) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:407) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/accent.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0c00b2
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2640)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.<init>(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:155)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.DatePicker.createCalendarUIDelegate(DatePicker.java:160)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:140)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:126)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:122)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at .fragment.NewFavoriteFragment$DatePickerFragment.onCreateDialog(NewFavoriteFragment.java:437) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:407) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:115)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1215)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1124)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2630)
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.<init>(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:155) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.DatePicker.createCalendarUIDelegate(DatePicker.java:160) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:140) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:126) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:122) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at .fragment.NewFavoriteFragment$DatePickerFragment.onCreateDialog(NewFavoriteFragment.java:437) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:407) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-03 13:33:12.769 25371-25371/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My Gradle file:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+')
compile('com.android.support:design:22.2.0')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0')
compile('com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0')
```

Comment: Are you using `appcompat-v7` (e.g., inheriting from `AppCompatActivity`)? If so, try using `AppCompatDialogFragment` instead of `DialogFragment`.

Comment: yes my Activities are subclassing `AppCompatActivity` but it cannot resolve `AppCompatDialogFragment ` when I try using it.  Also updated the question with the support libraries I am using

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with your code @pgiitu i would recommend updating to 23.1.0 and try it out. cuz that is the only difference between my code and urs